# facet_grid with ggbarplot is plotting the one set multiple times

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid, ggpubr

I am trying to make a stacked bar graph with error bars split into three graphs by time. Here is the raw data:

```
   Replicate Sample Time Stage Percent
1           1 WT Veh  24h    G1   85.67
2           2 WT Veh  24h    G1   82.77
3           3 WT Veh  24h    G1   83.28
4           1 WT Veh  24h    G2    9.14
5           2 WT Veh  24h    G2   10.37
6           3 WT Veh  24h    G2   11.60
7           1 WT Veh  24h     S    5.20
8           2 WT Veh  24h     S    6.87
9           3 WT Veh  24h     S    5.12
10          1  WT E2  24h    G1   61.78
11          2  WT E2  24h    G1   54.48
12          3  WT E2  24h    G1   58.55
13          1  WT E2  24h    G2    8.10
14          2  WT E2  24h    G2   12.35
15          3  WT E2  24h    G2   10.43
16          1  WT E2  24h     S   30.12
17          2  WT E2  24h     S   33.17
18          3  WT E2  24h     S   31.02
19          1 KO Veh  24h    G1   79.86
20          2 KO Veh  24h    G1   75.95
21          3 KO Veh  24h    G1   80.96
22          1 KO Veh  24h    G2   11.39
23          2 KO Veh  24h    G2   12.90
24          3 KO Veh  24h    G2    9.93
25          1 KO Veh  24h     S    8.75
26          2 KO Veh  24h     S   11.15
27          3 KO Veh  24h     S    9.11
28          1  KO E2  24h    G1   56.98
29          2  KO E2  24h    G1   49.49
30          3  KO E2  24h    G1   51.66
31          1  KO E2  24h    G2   16.65
32          2  KO E2  24h    G2   17.39
33          3  KO E2  24h    G2   15.28
34          1  KO E2  24h     S   26.37
35          2  KO E2  24h     S   33.12
36          3  KO E2  24h     S   33.06
37          1 WT Veh  48h    G1   86.57
38          2 WT Veh  48h    G1   88.80
39          3 WT Veh  48h    G1   84.36
40          1 WT Veh  48h    G2    7.27
41          2 WT Veh  48h    G2    7.27
42          3 WT Veh  48h    G2    9.91
43          1 WT Veh  48h     S    6.16
44          2 WT Veh  48h     S    3.94
45          3 WT Veh  48h     S    5.73
46          1  WT E2  48h    G1   65.06
47          2  WT E2  48h    G1   67.54
48          3  WT E2  48h    G1   71.00
49          1  WT E2  48h    G2    6.55
50          2  WT E2  48h    G2    8.06
51          3  WT E2  48h    G2    7.06
52          1  WT E2  48h     S   28.39
53          2  WT E2  48h     S   24.40
54          3  WT E2  48h     S   21.94
55          1 KO Veh  48h    G1   79.23
56          2 KO Veh  48h    G1   80.89
57          3 KO Veh  48h    G1   82.71
58          1 KO Veh  48h    G2   12.76
59          2 KO Veh  48h    G2   11.20
60          3 KO Veh  48h    G2    8.64
61          1 KO Veh  48h     S    8.00
62          2 KO Veh  48h     S    7.91
63          3 KO Veh  48h     S    8.66
64          1  KO E2  48h    G1   62.71
65          2  KO E2  48h    G1   56.54
66          3  KO E2  48h    G1   60.17
67          1  KO E2  48h    G2   12.16
68          2  KO E2  48h    G2   15.71
69          3  KO E2  48h    G2   13.68
70          1  KO E2  48h     S   25.13
71          2  KO E2  48h     S   27.75
72          3  KO E2  48h     S   26.16
73          1 WT Veh  72h    G1   88.56
74          2 WT Veh  72h    G1   86.13
75          3 WT Veh  72h    G1   86.63
76          1 WT Veh  72h    G2    6.42
77          2 WT Veh  72h    G2    7.21
78          3 WT Veh  72h    G2    9.17
79          1 WT Veh  72h     S    5.02
80          2 WT Veh  72h     S    6.66
81          3 WT Veh  72h     S    4.21
82          1  WT E2  72h    G1   75.00
83          2  WT E2  72h    G1   68.69
84          3  WT E2  72h    G1   72.46
85          1  WT E2  72h    G2    7.53
86          2  WT E2  72h    G2   12.33
87          3  WT E2  72h    G2    8.15
88          1  WT E2  72h     S   17.46
89          2  WT E2  72h     S   18.98
90          3  WT E2  72h     S   19.39
91          1 KO Veh  72h    G1   78.14
92          2 KO Veh  72h    G1   82.40
93          3 KO Veh  72h    G1   84.60
94          1 KO Veh  72h    G2   14.35
95          2 KO Veh  72h    G2   11.35
96          3 KO Veh  72h    G2    8.41
97          1 KO Veh  72h     S    7.52
98          2 KO Veh  72h     S    6.25
99          3 KO Veh  72h     S    6.98
100         1  KO E2  72h    G1   63.55
101         2  KO E2  72h    G1   64.26
102         3  KO E2  72h    G1   72.20
103         1  KO E2  72h    G2   11.89
104         2  KO E2  72h    G2   12.98
105         3  KO E2  72h    G2   10.57
106         1  KO E2  72h     S   24.56
107         2  KO E2  72h     S   22.77
108         3  KO E2  72h     S   17.23
```

At first glance, it seems like I am able to make the graph I want successfully using the following:

```
library(ggpubr)

df <- read.csv("raw-cell-cycle-data.csv")
df$Time <- factor(df$Time, levels = c("24h", "48h", "72h"), ordered = T)
df$Stage <- factor(df$Stage, levels = c("S", "G2", "G1"), ordered = T)
df$Sample <- factor(df$Sample, levels = c("WT Veh", "WT E2", "KO Veh", "KO E2", ordered = T))

colors <- c("#8c8c8c", "#f2f2f2", "#1a1a1a")

ggbarplot(df, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  facet_grid(~ Time)
```

Resulting plot:
[stacked bar plot attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azEvM.png)

However, if you examine the plot carefully you'll notice that the bar plots are exactly the same for each time point. Plotting the three time points individually, you will see that this most certainly is not the case:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- filter(df, Time == "24h")
data2 <- filter(df, Time == "48h")
data3 <- filter(df, Time == "72h")

p <- ggbarplot(data1, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
p

q <- ggbarplot(data2, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
q

r <- ggbarplot(data3, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
r

arranged_graph <- ggarrange(p,q,r, ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
arranged_graph
```

Resulting plot:
[Arranged graph of individual time points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fElRT.png)

The differences between the time points may be subtle, but there are differences nonetheless!

What is going on here that is causing facet_grid to repeat the data multiple times? Worst case I can make something work using the individual plots, but it would be great to understand what is going on with facet_grid!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Figured it out! The solution is to add facet.by = "Time" in the ggbarplot call. So in summary:

```
ggbarplot(df, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors, facet.by = "Time") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) +
```

Which produces the following: [New plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8hQ.png)

I'm guessing facet_grid doesn't play well with ggpubr!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `facet.by=` option in the `ggbarplot()` function, I think you'll get what you want:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Replicate, ~Sample, ~Time, ~Stage, ~Percent,
1, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   85.67,
2, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   82.77,
3, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   83.28,
1, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G2",    9.14,
2, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G2",   10.37,
3, "WT Veh",  "24h",    "G2",   11.60,
1, "WT Veh",  "24h",     "S",    5.20,
2, "WT Veh",  "24h",     "S",    6.87,
3, "WT Veh",  "24h",     "S",    5.12,
1,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G1",   61.78,
2,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G1",   54.48,
3,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G1",   58.55,
1,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G2",    8.10,
2,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G2",   12.35,
3,  "WT E2",  "24h",    "G2",   10.43,
1,  "WT E2",  "24h",     "S",   30.12,
2,  "WT E2",  "24h",     "S",   33.17,
3,  "WT E2",  "24h",     "S",   31.02,
1, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   79.86,
2, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   75.95,
3, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G1",   80.96,
1, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G2",   11.39,
2, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G2",   12.90,
3, "KO Veh",  "24h",    "G2",    9.93,
1, "KO Veh",  "24h",     "S",    8.75,
2, "KO Veh",  "24h",     "S",   11.15,
3, "KO Veh",  "24h",     "S",    9.11,
1,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G1",   56.98,
2,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G1",   49.49,
3,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G1",   51.66,
1,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G2",   16.65,
2,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G2",   17.39,
3,  "KO E2",  "24h",    "G2",   15.28,
1,  "KO E2",  "24h",     "S",   26.37,
2,  "KO E2",  "24h",     "S",   33.12,
3,  "KO E2",  "24h",     "S",   33.06,
1, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   86.57,
2, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   88.80,
3, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   84.36,
1, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G2",    7.27,
2, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G2",    7.27,
3, "WT Veh",  "48h",    "G2",    9.91,
1, "WT Veh",  "48h",     "S",    6.16,
2, "WT Veh",  "48h",     "S",    3.94,
3, "WT Veh",  "48h",     "S",    5.73,
1,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G1",   65.06,
2,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G1",   67.54,
3,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G1",   71.00,
1,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G2",    6.55,
2,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G2",    8.06,
3,  "WT E2",  "48h",    "G2",    7.06,
1,  "WT E2",  "48h",     "S",   28.39,
2,  "WT E2",  "48h",     "S",   24.40,
3,  "WT E2",  "48h",     "S",   21.94,
1, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   79.23,
2, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   80.89,
3, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G1",   82.71,
1, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G2",   12.76,
2, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G2",   11.20,
3, "KO Veh",  "48h",    "G2",    8.64,
1, "KO Veh",  "48h",     "S",    8.00,
2, "KO Veh",  "48h",     "S",    7.91,
3, "KO Veh",  "48h",     "S",    8.66,
1,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G1",   62.71,
2,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G1",   56.54,
3,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G1",   60.17,
1,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G2",   12.16,
2,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G2",   15.71,
3,  "KO E2",  "48h",    "G2",   13.68,
1,  "KO E2",  "48h",     "S",   25.13,
2,  "KO E2",  "48h",     "S",   27.75,
3,  "KO E2",  "48h",     "S",   26.16,
1, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   88.56,
2, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   86.13,
3, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   86.63,
1, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G2",    6.42,
2, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G2",    7.21,
3, "WT Veh",  "72h",    "G2",    9.17,
1, "WT Veh",  "72h",     "S",    5.02,
2, "WT Veh",  "72h",     "S",    6.66,
3, "WT Veh",  "72h",     "S",    4.21,
1,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G1",   75.00,
2,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G1",   68.69,
3,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G1",   72.46,
1,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G2",    7.53,
2,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G2",   12.33,
3,  "WT E2",  "72h",    "G2",    8.15,
1,  "WT E2",  "72h",     "S",   17.46,
2,  "WT E2",  "72h",     "S",   18.98,
3,  "WT E2",  "72h",     "S",   19.39,
1, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   78.14,
2, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   82.40,
3, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G1",   84.60,
1, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G2",   14.35,
2, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G2",   11.35,
3, "KO Veh",  "72h",    "G2",    8.41,
1, "KO Veh",  "72h",     "S",    7.52,
2, "KO Veh",  "72h",     "S",    6.25,
3, "KO Veh",  "72h",     "S",    6.98,
1,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G1",   63.55,
2,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G1",   64.26,
3,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G1",   72.20,
1,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G2",   11.89,
2,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G2",   12.98,
3,  "KO E2",  "72h",    "G2",   10.57,
1,  "KO E2",  "72h",     "S",   24.56,
2,  "KO E2",  "72h",     "S",   22.77,
3,  "KO E2",  "72h",     "S",   17.23)


library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df$Time <- factor(df$Time, levels = c("24h", "48h", "72h"), ordered = T)
df$Stage <- factor(df$Stage, levels = c("S", "G2", "G1"), ordered = T)
df$Sample <- factor(df$Sample, levels = c("WT Veh", "WT E2", "KO Veh", "KO E2", ordered = T))

colors <- c("#8c8c8c", "#f2f2f2", "#1a1a1a")

ggbarplot(df, x = "Sample", y = "Percent", add = "mean_se", color = "black", fill = "Stage", palette = colors, facet.by = "Time") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>